# Azure Pipelines - Output variable from python script file to pipeline variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I've tried several articles and threads from Stackoverflow but can't seem to get anywhere. I am trying to take a variable from a .py file which is called in a YAML step and set that variable globally to be used.

In my .**py file** i have

```
print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable=AMLPipelineId;isOutput=true]{pipelineId}')
```

Then in my YAML pipeline step i have

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Run AML Pipeline'
   inputs:
     azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
     ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
     name: AmlPipeline
     azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
     pwsh: true
     Inline: |
             $username = "$(ARM_CLIENT_ID)"
             $password = "$(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)"
             $tenantId = "$(ARM_TENANT_ID)"
                  
             python $(Pipeline.Workspace)/AML_Pipeline/build_aml_pipeline.py --wsName $(wsName) --resourceGroup $(ResourceGroupName) --subscriptionId $(subId)

                 
             $MLPipelineId = $AmlPipeline.AMLPipelineId
```

But it seems like this variable is empty. I know there are other ways of using the "set variable" but this is my latest attempt i.e. something like `print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=version;]%s' % (version))`

My current approach i followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need `isOutput=true` - that's only needed for referencing variables between different jobs or stages.
2. ["You cannot use the variable in the step that it is defined."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script) - split that script into two steps: one that runs your `.py` file, second one that uses the newly defined variable.

Comment: I've updated my python code to `print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable=AMLPipelineId]{pipelineId}')` and i moved into a separate step: `$MLPipelineId = $AMLPipelineId` and its still empty.

Comment: Try using `$(AmlPipeline)` (syntax for referencing pipeline variables) or `$env:AmlPipeline` (pipeline variables are also automatically mapped to env variables).

Answer (score 5):

A very minimal example for everyone struggling with this. The documentation is kind of lacking on this for my taste. As @qbik said, dont set and use the variable in the same step, make it seperate steps.

## set_variable.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set name of the variable
    name = 'COLOR'
    # set value of the variable
    value = 'red'
    # set variable
    print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable={name};]{value}')
```

## azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.9'
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.9'
# run the script to set the variable
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: filePath
    scriptPath: set_variable.py
# now you can use the variable in the next step
- bash: echo my favorite color is: $(COLOR)
```

Now you can technically do all kinds of cool stuff in python, then set, and reference the variables in the following steps. In my case I have to extract specific package version numbers from a JSON/YAML file based on an id that is set earlier in the pipeline and parse the information as an args for a docker build. Hope that helps other people stumbling across this answer looking for a minimal working example :)

Answer (score 0):

I used `print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=<Variable-in-Pipeline]+<output-variable>')`

> Variable-in-Pipeline // the given name should be used in Azure Devops pipeline and should be added to pipeline variables as an empty string

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to pass variables between tasks on Azure on a release pipeline's agent job and the following worked for me:

`print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=<PipelineVariable>;isOutput=true;]'+<OutputVariable>)`

Then when you want to access the variable in subsequent steps use:

`$(<PipelineVariable>.<OutputVariable>)`

And specify your `<PipelineVariable>` on your Python task as follows:
[image]